# Retrieve image from parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, icarousel

I would want to to use two carousel using the icarousel to display images from parse. This is my the  code when retrieving images from the document folder.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        return [items1 count];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TopsC"];
        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
        [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [items2 count];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BottomC"];
        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];
        [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    }
}
```

ITEMS

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"ooooo");
    //set up data sources
    self.items1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [items1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    self.items2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 65; i < 65 + 58; i++)
    {
        [items2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", i]];
    }
}
```

However I don't nothing is displayed for the carousel. Why is it not importing photo from parse?

Comment: PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TopsC]; - You forgot the right quote.

Comment: @etolstoy Thats just a copy paste mistake sorry.  Its quoted on my Xcode project.

Comment: I've never worked with parse, but it seems, that your code isn't executed, because you call return function in the first line of every block.

Comment: ＠etolstoy　I put the return at the bottom but does not work.

Comment: And what exactly is items1 and items2? Where do you declare them?

Comment: @etolstoy items1 and 2 are the carousel itself I am putting two carousels in one viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

First; the query code never gets run, as you start with returning `[items1 count];` 
Anything included after the return statement is ignored.

Second; There is nothing in the code you provided that return anything from Parse. Your data sources (items1/items2) get populated with numbers and strings in your `awakeFromNib`, but there is no contact with parse in this code. Except the queries for Topsc and BottomC, which is never executed. And even if they DID get executed, you don't trigger the queries. You just set them up.

So, to answer your question: you don't query parse for any images, and that's why the carousels don't get any images.